Animate items on composition after filtering and setting new items
I'm animating items when they enter composition inside a FlowRow, this also happens in LazyColumn/Row, Column either. When user filters getting data from default list and showing items based on some filter criteria. However, some items do not leave composition and enter so their LaunchedEffect(Unit) never gets called.
I tried changing data to be unstable, override equals to return false, using copy to pass new references, updating some id to check if displaying old data, using SnapshotStateList as in actual implementation with clear and add items but even with new data Composable do not get disposed and because of that do not get composed and animate after filtering.

@Preview
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val viewModel = viewModel<SomeViewModel>()
    MyComposable(viewModel)
}

@Composable
fun MyComposable(someViewModel: SomeViewModel) {

    Column {

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp).fillMaxWidth(),
            onClick = {
                someViewModel.filter()
            }
        ) {
            Text("Filter")
        }

        val itemList = someViewModel.itemList

        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        ) {

            val itemWidth = (maxWidth - 8.dp) / 2

            FlowRow(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                maxItemsInEachRow = 2,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {

                itemList.forEach {
                    key(it.id) {
                        MyRow(
                            modifier = Modifier.size(itemWidth),
                            item = it
                        )
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    item: SomeData,
) {

    var visible by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    var counter by remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        println("Composing $item")
        visible = true
    }

    val context = LocalContext.current

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item ${item.id} is leaving composition", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = visible,
        enter = fadeIn(
            tween(300)
        ) + scaleIn(
            tween(300)
        )
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = modifier
                .shadow(2.dp, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            Text("id: ${item.id}, value: ${item.value}")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                onClick = {
                    counter++
                }
            ) {
                Text("Counter: $counter")
            }
        }
    }
}

class SomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val list = listOf(
        SomeData(id = "1", value = "Row1"),
        SomeData(id = "2", value = "Row2"),
        SomeData(id = "3", value = "Row3"),
        SomeData(id = "4", value = "Row4"),
        SomeData(id = "5", value = "Row5")
    )

    var itemList by mutableStateOf(list)

    private var counter: Int = 0

    fun filter() {
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            itemList = listOf(
                list[0],
                list[1],
                list[2]
            )
        } else if (counter % 3 == 1) {
            itemList = listOf(
                list[1],
                list[2]
            )
        } else {
            itemList = listOf(
                list[2],
                list[3]
            )
        }

        counter++
    }
}

data class SomeData(val id: String, val value: String)

Another sample with some unique id and copy function to pass new references

class SomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val list = listOf(
        SomeData(id = "1", value = "Row1"),
        SomeData(id = "2", value = "Row2"),
        SomeData(id = "3", value = "Row3"),
        SomeData(id = "4", value = "Row4"),
        SomeData(id = "5", value = "Row5")
    )

    var itemList by mutableStateOf(list)

    private var counter: Int = 0

    fun filter() {
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            itemList = listOf(
                list[0].copy(uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()),
                list[1].copy(uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()),
                list[2].copy(uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            )
        } else if (counter % 3 == 1) {
            itemList = listOf(
                list[1].copy(uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()),
                list[2].copy(uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            )
        } else {
            itemList = listOf(
                list[2].copy(uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()),
                list[3].copy(uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            )
        }

        counter++
    }
}

data class SomeData(val id: String, val value: String, var uniqueId:String = "")

Edit
I solved it by using uniqueId as key
itemList.forEach {
    key(it.uniqueKey) {
        MyRow(
            modifier = Modifier.size(itemWidth),
            item = it
        )
    }
}

for reproducing the issue, it's possible to make items leave and enter composition if keys don't match with previous values in any index but i'm looking for a way to solve it without a data class with mutable params and definitely without any coupling between a Composable contains FlowRow and ViewModel. In real implementation FlowRow only gets items, filtering is done via another Composable.
It might be possible to have items enter/leave composition by using data with some distinction check like AnimatedContent or AnimatedVisibility does to have separate states.

I solved this in 2 ways but first way is not i preferred for my implementation because it removes every item from composition and in a scrollable list/LazyColumn desired animation runs below visible area.
class SomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val list = listOf(
        SomeData(id = "1", value = "Row1"),
        SomeData(id = "2", value = "Row2"),
        SomeData(id = "3", value = "Row3"),
        SomeData(id = "4", value = "Row4"),
        SomeData(id = "5", value = "Row5")
    )

    var itemList by mutableStateOf(list)

    var filter: Int = 0

    fun filter() {
        if (filter % 3 == 0) {
            itemList = listOf(
                list[0],
                list[1],
                list[2]
            )
        } else if (filter % 3 == 1) {
            itemList = listOf(
                list[1],
                list[2]
            )
        } else {
            itemList = listOf(
                list[0],
                list[2],
                list[3]
            )
        }

        filter++
    }
}

data class SomeData(val id: String, val value: String)

pass this filter in ViewModel to Composable that contains FlowRow
@Composable
fun MyComposable(someViewModel: SomeViewModel) {

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(backgroundColor)) {

        val itemList = someViewModel.itemList

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)
        ) {

            items(5) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                        .fillMaxWidth().height(100.dp)
                )
            }

            item {
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp).fillMaxWidth(),
                    onClick = {
                        someViewModel.filter()
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Filter")
                }
            }
            item {
                StaggeredList(
                    filter = someViewModel.filter.toString(),
                    itemList = itemList
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

And in this composable key(it.id + filter) to remove every item from composition when filter changes but this approach makes items below visible area since every item is removed and enters to composition in a LazyColumn.
@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Composable
private fun StaggeredList(
    filter: String,
    itemList: List<SomeData>,
) {
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
    ) {

        val itemWidth = (maxWidth - 8.dp) / 2

        FlowRow(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            maxItemsInEachRow = 2,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            itemList.forEachIndexed { index, it ->
                key(it.id + filter) {

                    var visible by remember {
                        mutableStateOf(false)
                    }

                    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                        visible = false
                        println("Composing ${it.id},")
                        delay(250)
                        visible = true
                    }

                    AnimatedVisibility(
                        visible = visible,
                        enter = fadeIn(tween(250)) +
                                slideInVertically(tween(250)) {
                                    it / 2
                                },
                        exit = fadeOut(tween(250)) + slideOutVertically(tween(250)) {
                            it / 2
                        }
                    ) {
                        MyRow(
                            modifier = Modifier.size(itemWidth, 200.dp),
                            item = it
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

In second approach i used same key, but using filter as LaunchedEffect key to restart animation but this time fadeIn() and fadeOut animations stopped working.
    key(it.id) {

                    var visible by remember {
                        mutableStateOf(false)
                    }

                    LaunchedEffect(filter) {
                        visible = false
                        println("Composing ${it.id},")
                        delay(250)
                        visible = true
                    }
 }

And Row composable is
@Composable
fun MyRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    item: SomeData,
) {

    var counter by remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .shadow(2.dp, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
            .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            "id: ${item.id}, value: ${item.value}"
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            onClick = {
                counter++
            }
        ) {
            Text("Counter: $counter")
        }
    }
}

