How to fix drag and drop task bug in jetpack compose?
I'm trying to write an answer to this question, but while testing my code, i discovered a bug that i couldn’t figure out how to fix.
The app is a task manager where you can drag and drop tasks between queues: To Do, In Progress, and Done. Each queue has a list of tasks, and dragging a task moves it from one queue to another.
Here's a minimal example of my code to reproduce the issue:
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.8.5")

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                App(modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(innerPadding)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

enum class QueueType(val title: String) {
    TodoQueue("To Do"),
    InProgressQueue("In Progress"),
    DoneQueue("Done")
}


data class Task(
    val title: String,
    val description: String
)

class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {

    val todoTasks = mutableStateListOf<Task>(
        Task("Task 1", "Description 1"),
        Task("Task 4", "Description 4"),
    )

    val inProgressTasks = mutableStateListOf<Task>(
        Task("Task 2", "Description 2"),
        Task("Task 5", "Description 5"),
    )

    val doneTasks = mutableStateListOf<Task>(
        Task("Task 3", "Description 3"),
    )

    fun moveTask(
        task: Task,
        from: QueueType,
        to: QueueType
    ) {
        when(from) {
            QueueType.TodoQueue -> todoTasks.remove(task)
            QueueType.InProgressQueue -> inProgressTasks.remove(task)
            QueueType.DoneQueue -> doneTasks.remove(task)
        }
        when(to) {
            QueueType.TodoQueue -> todoTasks.add(task)
            QueueType.InProgressQueue -> inProgressTasks.add(task)
            QueueType.DoneQueue -> doneTasks.add(task)
        }
    }
}

data class DraggedData(
    val task: Task,
    val originQueue: QueueType,
)

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun TaskCard(
    task: Task,
    queueType: QueueType,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .dragAndDropSource {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onLongPress = {
                        startTransfer(
                            DragAndDropTransferData(
                                ClipData.newPlainText("Task", "Task"),

                                //passe data to be used later when dropping the card
                                localState = DraggedData(task, queueType)
                            )
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
            .background(
                color = Color.LightGray,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
            )
            .padding(vertical = 4.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = task.title)
        Text(text = task.description)
    }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun QueueTask(
    queueType: QueueType,
    tasks: List<Task>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onTaskDrop: (Task, QueueType) -> Unit
) {
    val dropTarget = remember {
        object : DragAndDropTarget {
            override fun onDrop(dragStartEvent: DragAndDropEvent): Boolean {
                val dropEvent = dragStartEvent.toAndroidDragEvent()

                // get the dragged data from localState passed earlier 
                val draggedTaskData = dropEvent.localState as? DraggedData
                val droppedTask = draggedTaskData?.task
                droppedTask?.let { onTaskDrop(it, draggedTaskData.originQueue) }
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .dragAndDropTarget (
                shouldStartDragAndDrop = { dragStartEvent ->
                    dragStartEvent.mimeTypes().contains(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)
                }, target = dropTarget
            )
            .border(
                width = 1.dp,
                color = Color.Black,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
            )
            .fillMaxHeight(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(text = queueType.title)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
        tasks.forEach { task ->
            TaskCard(
                task = task,
                queueType = queueType,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(vertical = 4.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun App(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
) {

    val todoTasks = viewModel.todoTasks
    val inProgressTasks = viewModel.inProgressTasks
    val doneTasks = viewModel.doneTasks

    Row(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
    ) {
        QueueTask(
            queueType = QueueType.TodoQueue,
            tasks = todoTasks,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            onTaskDrop = { task, fromQueueType ->
                viewModel.moveTask(task, fromQueueType, QueueType.TodoQueue)
            }
        )
        QueueTask(
            queueType = QueueType.InProgressQueue,
            tasks = inProgressTasks,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            onTaskDrop = { task, fromQueueType ->
                viewModel.moveTask(task, fromQueueType, QueueType.InProgressQueue)
            }
        )
        QueueTask(
            queueType = QueueType.DoneQueue,
            tasks = doneTasks,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            onTaskDrop = { task, fromQueueType ->
                viewModel.moveTask(task, fromQueueType, QueueType.DoneQueue)
            }
        )
    }
}

The code mostly works, but in some scenarios, unexpected behavior occurs:
Scenario 1:

Move Task 2 from In Progress to To Do --> Works fine.
Move Task 1 from To Do to In Progress --> Works fine.
Move Task 4 from To Do to In Progress --> BUG: "Task 1" is duplicated, and Task 4 doesn't move.


Scenario 2:

Move Task 1 from To Do to To Do (same queue) --> works fine.
Move Task 4 from To Do to To Do (same queue) --> BUG: nothing happens.


When debugging, i noticed that sometimes the wrong task is passed to the onTaskDrop lambda. For example, even though i'm dragging Task 1, a different task gets processed.
It seem like the localState passed in the drag and drop process might not always match the dragged task.
The issue seems related to task ordering in the queue!
What could be causing these issues, and how can i fix them?

Please use a key to tell Compose how to uniquely identify each TaskCard in your QueueTask Composable. Then Jetpack Compose can remove exactly the one TaskCard Composable corresponding to the removed object from the tasks List.
tasks.forEach { task ->
    key(task.title) {
        TaskCard(
            task = task,
            queueType = queueType,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 4.dp)
        )
    }
}

I could not quite figure out under which exact circumstances the code without key starts to fail, but I now just follow the practice to always specify a key whenever I display Composables in a forEach loop on data that can change.
Note that in production code, you would add a unique ID to the Task class instead of using the title as a key.

Thank you, it works perfectly! i didn’t know that key could be used with regular Column/Row. I thought it was only for LazyColumn/LazyRow

key fails if you want to do some filtering for instance if you want each item to leave/enter composition. It still uses the same item even if you change instance with copy because it uses equals. Let's say you have an item in index 3, if in next composition if this item with same equals available even if in another some index it doesn't leave recomposition.

@Thracian Do you mean that when the tasks List is reordered, the items will not correctly rearrange themselves when using key? Or do you mean it will reuse the existing Composables instead of generating a fresh TaskCard Composable list after filtering?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/79193267/5457853 here i added a mutable param to change key for instance. This is something that i worked on for a day to figure out though. keys check for equals, and for data classes it's params of primary constructor, not referential equality

However, as mentioned in answer using key is almost always mandatory especially with stateful Composables if your list is subject to remove/add operations to track Composable not by positions or indices but these keys. Otherwise, stateful Composables return incorrect states. And this is example to how not using keys fail.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76244495/problem-with-deleting-object-in-jetpack-compose If you don't use keys with lists that add or delete with stateful Composable you get wrong states. And when you use key you should know that equals check is done

@BenjyTec i meant not for this but in general using equal keys will keep same composable in composition even if its index change due to deleting, adding, swapping or shuffling. Let's say you want some state to be cleared in a composable after list change but it won't because it's still in composition and will be recomposed

Okay thanks for the info, I think I now understood. Using key can be problematic if you need all your items to freshly enter the composition after the tasks list changed, as you needed it in your question to correctly apply the enter animation.

Yes, exactly. keys can be problematic if you want Composable to exit and re-enter composition or reset after some task with your list. And in cases you don't use keys then you see wrong states for Composables
